# Beautiful Soup | Extract Variable from java Script

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

lighters,

I am using beautiful soup to scrape data from an HTML page that have several columns under Table body.

Please below the mocked code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import urllib.request as urllib2

import re

import json


app_page = urllib2.urlopen(myUrl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(app_page)

print(soup.prettify())

data  = soup.find_all("script")[7]

data=re.sub("\n","",str(data))

print(data)
```

Output:

```css
<script type="text/javascript">              var appsTableData=[[<"<a href='Something'/>"]]</script>
```

```
p = re.compile('              var appsTableData=(.*?)')"

print(p)

m = p.match(str(data))

print(m)
```

**Output: None**

I am not sure why the regular expression is failing to recognize the variable.

Comment: Your question was very hard to read. The reason why it's failing is because `.*?` is lazy. Changing it to greedy will not work either, you will need something to tell it where to stop matching.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.string` to the text and then use `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
data = soup.find_all("script")[7].string 
print(data.replace("var appsTableData=", ""))
```

**Output:**

```
[[<"<a href='Something'/>"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

using beautifulsoup and `re.compile`

```
data = '''<script type="text/javascript">              var appsTableData=[[<"<a href='Something'/>"]]</script>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

withbs = soup.find('script', string=re.compile('var appsTableData'))
withbs = withbs.text.replace('var appsTableData=', '').strip()
print(withbs)
```

using `re` without `bs4`, `match` tries to match the entire string, use `search` instead

```
withre = re.search('var appsTableData=(.*?)<script', data).group(1)
print(withre)
```

results:

```
[[<"<a href='Something'/>"]]
```